# matTooltip not displaying in a dialog window

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular application I am using the `matTooltip` (https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) from inside a `dialog` window (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). The tooltips fail to display when used in conjunction with elements inside the dialog. Outside of the dialog they are working correctly. How can I get tooltips working inside a dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Without any of your source code, I can't provide an accurate answer. But in my own experiences I've adjusted the z-index of the tooltip to make sure it wasn't layered behind the dialog.

Inspect the DOM element and hover your mouse over where the tooltip should be. If it's successfully displaying then you should see a change in the inspected HTML. If not you might not be using it properly.